# Draw horizontal ray/line/grid

Tags: java, android, flutter, charts, syncfusion

I want to draw a so called 'horizontal ray' or 'horizontal line' for some y points. I cannot find any option to do so for my charts. I tried using markers or even data labels but they are irrelevant. I'm currently using syncfusion library for drawing charts. Here is the image:

Image:
[image]

How can I achieve this?

this is the code I'm currently using, cartesian charts:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

class ChartAl extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChartPageState createState() => _ChartPageState();
}

late List<ChartData> chartData;

class _ChartPageState extends State<ChartAl> {
  late SelectionBehavior _selectionBehavior;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _selectionBehavior = SelectionBehavior(
        // Enables the selection
        enable: true);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    chartData = getData();

    return Container(
      child: SfCartesianChart(
        primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(),
        primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(
            intervalType: DateTimeIntervalType.days,
            visibleMinimum: chartData[chartData.length - 29].x,
            visibleMaximum: chartData[chartData.length - 1].x),
        zoomPanBehavior: ZoomPanBehavior(
          enablePanning: true,
        ),
        series: <CartesianSeries<ChartData, DateTime>>[
          LineSeries(
            initialSelectedDataIndexes: <int>[2],
            selectionBehavior: SelectionBehavior(
              enable: true,
            ),
            // markerSettings: MarkerSettings(
            //   isVisible: true,
            //   shape: DataMarkerType.horizontalLine
            // ),
            // dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(
            //     // Renders the data label
            //     isVisible: true),
            dataSource: chartData,
            xValueMapper: (ChartData tendencias, _) => tendencias.x,
            yValueMapper: (ChartData tendencias, _) => tendencias.y,
          )
        ],
        annotations: <CartesianChartAnnotation>[
          CartesianChartAnnotation(
            widget: Container(
              height: 1.0,
              width: 200,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            coordinateUnit: CoordinateUnit.point,
            x: DateTime(2018, 1, 10),
            y: 20,
            horizontalAlignment: ChartAlignment.near,
          )
        ],
        trackballBehavior: TrackballBehavior(
            enable: true,
            lineType: TrackballLineType.horizontal,
            tooltipSettings:
                InteractiveTooltip(enable: true, color: Colors.red)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

dynamic getData() {
  List<ChartData> data = [];
  for (int i = 1; i < 35; i++) {
    data.add(ChartData(DateTime(2018, 1, i), getRandomInt(10, 100).toInt()));
  }
  return data;
}

num getRandomInt(num min, num max) {
  final Random random = Random();
  return min + random.nextInt((max - min).toInt());
}

class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.x, this.y);
  final DateTime x;
  final int y;
}
```

I tried to draw it with a container with some width but as you see it does not work.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet, share a sample widget that you've tried so far? It will be easy with context by extending instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: I added it you can see now, I want it for cartesian charts, but it does not work, and I cannot find any related thing in the documentations: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/marker-datalabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recommend that you can use the **PlotBand** feature available in our chart widget to render horizontal line for y-points in the chart. We have also attached a simple chart sample below in which have rendered a horizontal line in the chart using the **PlotBand** feature.

```
SfCartesianChart( 
            primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(), 
            primaryYAxis: NumericAxis( 
              plotBands: [ 
                PlotBand( 
                  start: 32, // y-point for with the horizontal line needs to be drawn. 
                  end: 32, 
                  borderColor: Colors.red, 
                  borderWidth: 2, // set the border width for the horizontal line. 
                  associatedAxisStart: DateTime(2002) // set the required value for assicoated x-axis start  property 
                ) 
              ] 
 
            ), 
)
```

[image: Screenshot plotband]

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/347691/ze/f170191_plotband-902619107

For further reference on the **Plotband** feature, please check the user guide below.
https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/axis-customization#plot-line

Also, to mention that, if you require to render the line on tapping on the chart, you can use the on PixelToPoint method to achieve it. Please find the sample link below for further reference.
https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/cartesian-charts/user-interactions/add-a-point-on-click